# cannot open file 'SOIL.libkernel32.lib'

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, soil

I need use SOIL library in my project. My steps:

1. download and extract zip to my project folder
2. rename libSOIL.a to SOIL.lib
3. Properties >> C/C++>General >> Additional include directories - Add "./SOIL/src"
4. Properties >> Linker >> General >> Additional Library Directories - Add "SOIL.lib"
5. put #include "SOIL.h"

Function *SOIL_load_image* was found but

error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SOIL.libkernel32.lib'

Answer (score 17):

I know this question is a couple weeks old now, but I figured it can't hurt.

The actual error you are getting is (probably) because you are missing a semicolon in the list of libraries to link.

If you go to Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies (which I assume you must have gone to, though it isn't in your list of steps), it should say something like `SOIL.lib%(AdditionalDependencies)`.

If you change that to `SOIL.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)` (note the semicolon!), then that error should disappear.

What `%(AdditionalDependencies)` does is append some other libraries that Microsoft knows (or thinks) that you will need.  The first of those is `kernel.lib`, so without a semicolon to seperate your `SOIL.lib` and `kernel.lib`, the linker tries to find `SOIL.libkernel.lib`, which does not exist!!

Comment: Thanks a million! This was really hard to figure out based on the error message.

Comment: Yeah, and it is so easy to accidently paste something on top of! I've wasted a bit of time on it... :)

Comment: You're the God!! It took me hours to find this missing f*** semicolon

Answer (score 2):

And here

> 2) rename libSOIL.a to SOIL.lib

you went all wrong. The name `libSOIL.a` indicates that you downloaded a build intended to be used with a GCC toolchain. Libraries with a filename to the scheme of `lib….a` use a different format than libraries named `….lib`.

You need a SOIL build for VC++.

Comment: I can not find SOIL build for VC++ to download.:(

Comment: @Hricer: SOIL is Open Source. You can (and should) build it yourself.

Comment: i'm really sorry for my ignorance but how build SOIL for vc++ in VS2012

Comment: @Hricer: I think the easiest in your case would be, that you simply copied the SOIL source files into your project and just add the source files to your project. Since SOIL is in the public domain this is perfectly fine to do.